# ASP.NET Modal called from multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

On a asp.net C# application, I have a modal to create a new item in the database.
The modal is very simple: A textbox for item description and a "OK"/"cancel" buttons. When press OK, stores the new item in database by AJAX call to controller.

I need to use this modal in multiple places of the application, so i would replicate modal code on every page I want to use this modal.

I´m sure theres a better way to do it in asp.net which encapsulates all content about new item creation as one "component" or anything
¿Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: You could use a partial view assuming it's the same controller you're calling each time.

Comment: Yes, but can include JS functions related to new item management in the partial view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you provide some code examples. A JS function will hit anything that's available in the DOM.